# Storing a bean during a Batch Job

Tags: cdi, batch-processing, java-ee-7

How can a CDI bean be stored for the entire duration of Batch Job?

I have a Chunk Job that i would like to monitor. I though i could do with a Bean Instance which scoped during the entire duration of the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really feasible to do this.  Serialization doesn't work quite the way most people think for CDI.

What I would recommend is having your batch job fire events at various points and use cDI to observe those events and take action.

You could also develop a custom scope for the batch and use it that way, but if you end up with multiple nodes executing the batch job it won't work quite right.